# Getting the coordinates of the parent object

Tags: unity-game-engine

how can I get the coordinates of the parent object so that they address their parents separately. That is, there is a prefab "Flag", there are 3 such objects on the stage. When they click on them, they create another object instead of themselves. So what is the question. It's about getting the coordinates of the parent object from which it is created.

/I know, I wrote nonsense and porridge...

Code on request:

```
public GameObject CreatingBuildingDeleting_FlagObject;

public GameObject CreatingBuilding_Barrack_FlagObject;
public GameObject CreatingBuilding_Tent_FlagObject;

float yPosition = 0.3f;
float Z_index = 5;

public void Build_Barrack()
{
    Replace(CreatingBuildingDeleting_FlagObject, CreatingBuilding_Barrack_FlagObject);

}
public void Build_Tent()
{
    Instantiate(CreatingBuilding_Tent_FlagObject);
    CreatingBuilding_Tent_FlagObject.transform.position = new Vector3(CreatingBuildingDeleting_FlagObject.transform.parent.position.x, yPosition, Z_index);
    Destroy(CreatingBuildingDeleting_FlagObject);
}

void Replace(GameObject ReplaceObject1, GameObject ReplaceObject2)
{
    Instantiate(ReplaceObject2, ReplaceObject2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(ReplaceObject1);
}
```

[image: This is how objects are created in the world]

What do prefabs look like on the stage and what am I trying to create other objects from:
[image: This is how objects are created in the world]

Answer (score 0):

Transform always has a reference to its parent transform!
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html
Alternatively, you could also subtract transform.localPosition from transform.position because the local variant is relative to the parent and "position" is global.

Comment: This works and I wrote code from this post from the documentation, but when prefabs start on the scene, objects take a 0, 0 coordinate.

Comment: Fear we won't be able to help in that case without more information. Show all relevant code and how the prefabs look like when instantiated in the world please.

Comment: I'll give you the information now.

Comment: That's it, I changed the question and provided the information. I can do more, if necessary.

Comment: @ВарионДракон Ah, you have a misconception of the Instantiate function. That function creates a "copy", aka an instance of the given game object or prefab you provide. It then RETURNS a reference to this new instance.
You want to set the position of this referenced, new object and not of your original sample. Look closer at: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: The article is useful and gave Me a couple of thoughts, but it doesn't help Me...

Comment: @ВарионДракон In that case I fear you have gotten yourself into a project above your level. Return to some more basic tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Actually now after closer looking at your code I think all you want to actually do would be

```
var position = new Vector3(CreatingBuildingDeleting_FlagObject.transform.position.x, yPosition, Z_index);
Instantiate(CreatingBuilding_Tent_FlagObject, position, Quaternion.idendity);
Destroy(CreatingBuildingDeleting_FlagObject);
```

---

Instances in the scene have **no reference/information whatsoever** about what original template they where cloned from.

-> You have to store and manage this on your own!

You could e.g. use a dedicated component on your original objects that you are going to clone

```
public class CloneInformation : MonoBehaviour
{
    // For storing the reference from where you have been cloned
    private CloneInformation _origin;
    // For public read-only acccess
    public CloneInformation Origin => _origin;

    // Optional you can even in the other direction also store direct children cloned from this object 
    private readonly HashSet<CloneInformation> clones = new HashSet<CloneInformation>(); 

    public void Initialize (CloneInformation origin)
    {
        _origin = origin;
        origin.clones.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        if(_origin)
        {
            _origin.clones.Remove(this);
        }
    }   
}
```

And then whenever you clone such an object do e.g

```
var originInformation = objectToClone.GetComponent<CloneInformation>();
var clonedInformation = Instantiate (originalInformation);
clonedInformation.Initialize(originalInformation);
```

This way you can now get the origin position using e.g.

```
var originPosition = someCloneInformation.Origin.transform.position;
```

and could even buble up to the most top ancestor using

```
CloneInformation someClone;
var position = Vector3.zero;

CloneInformation current = someClone.Origin;
while(current)
{
    position = current.transform.position;

    current = current.Origin;
}
```

Comment: Great idea, I'll try it now.

Comment: Everything would be fine, but only the second method (which you added after) sets the object to the 0 x coordinate

Comment: I added another screenshot to the question.

Comment: @ВарионДракон maybe the `.parent` is then not what you want to use?

Comment: Perhaps. In short, I am trying to achieve that instead of this object, another object appears on the same X coordinate.

Comment: After clicking on the button, I get it, but the X coordinate is not correct.

Comment: That's my whole problem.